# How do I install Windows XP on a USB flash drive?

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive

Please read this carefully. I want to actually run the OS *from the USB*,thus install it on it, not to copy the setup files to it. I have done some research on this, but doesn't help. I have an XP .iso file and a 32GB flash drive, if that helps. I have read some of the other threads and they can't help.

Comment: Yes it can be done, but not easy and does not work on all PC's. https://web.archive.org/web/20091228061152/http://www.ngine.de/index.jsp?pageid=4176

Comment: You're going to need 2 USBs - For the iso. Or you could try partitioning it

Comment: I can partition it with `diskpart` on my Win7 x64 on the HDD.